# Do operation on each in dynamic array

Tags: c, arrays, loops, memory, foreach

Suppose I have a `struct`

```
struct point_2d {
    int x,
    int y
};
```

Suppose in my program I keep an array of this type,

```
main()
{
    struct point_2d *coords = malloc(10*sizeof(struct point_2d));

    ...
}
```

and I want to do an operation on each of them (for example, set all points' coordinates to the origin or something).

Is there a way to loop through without having to know the length of the array (such as with strings, incrementing the pointer until `\0` is encountered), or do I need further input to determine that length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to loop through without having to know the length of the array (such as with strings, incrementing the pointer until \0 is encountered), or do I need further input to determine that length?

There is no way to loop without knowing how far to loop, unless you add a sentinel value to your array just as is done with C-strings and the `\0` termination. Even the `foreach()` loop in C++ has to aquire an iterator past the end of the container to know how far to loop.

Assuming, you allocated the memory with

```
int size = 10;
struct point_2d* coords = malloc(size*sizeof(*coords));
```

I'd recommend iterating through arrays with one of the following loop constructs:

- Forward:

  ```
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) coords[i].x = coords[i].y = 0;
  ```
- Backwards:

  ```
  for(int i = size; i--; ) coords[i].x = coords[i].y = 0;
  ```

That's hardly more to write than with a `foreach()` loop in other languages, and you see precisely what's happening.